# Kendo UI Grid Frozen column css - Frozen col not supporting CSS

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Kendo UI Grid Frozen column CSS class.

I have this Kendo UI grid with frozen row/column, I am adding some conditional formatting but unfortunately this conditional formatting not getting added to Frozen row/col

HTML

```
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Script

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
        },
        pageSize: 10
    },
    groupable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5
    },
    columns: [
        {
            field: "ContactName",
            title: "Contact Name",
            width: 175,
            locked: true
        }, {
            field: "ContactTitle",
            title: "Contact Title",
            width: 175
        }, {
            field: "CompanyName",
            title: "Company Name",
            width: 175
        }
    ]
    ,
    dataBound: onDataBound

});



function onDataBound(arg) {
        //console.log("Grid data bound");

        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var gridData = grid.dataSource.view();

        for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
            console.log(gridData[i].Status);
            //get the item uid
            var currentUid = gridData[i].uid;
            //if the record fits the custom condition
            if (gridData[i].ContactTitle =="Owner") {
                //find the row based on the uid and the custom class
                var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                $(currenRow).addClass("ClassDeleted");
            }
            else if (gridData[i].ContactTitle == "Sales Representative") {
                //find the row based on the uid and the custom class
                var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                $(currenRow).addClass("ClassPublished");
            }

            else if (gridData[i].ContactTitle == "Marketing Manager") {
                //find the row based on the uid and the custom class
                var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                $(currenRow).addClass("ClassSaved");
            }

            else if (gridData[i].ContactTitle == "Draft") {
                //find the row based on the uid and the custom class
                var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                $(currenRow).addClass("ClassSaved");
            }

            else if (gridData[i].ContactTitle == "Accounting Manager") {
                //find the row based on the uid and the custom class
                var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                $(currenRow).addClass("ClassCompleted");
            }



        }

    }
```

CSS

```
 .ClassDeleted {
        background-color: orangered;
    }

    .ClassPublished {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }

    .ClassCompleted {
        background-color: lightskyblue;
    }


    .ClassSaved {
        background-color: lightyellow;
    }
```

output coming as below: You can see CSS not applied to frozen column.

[image]

Any help here

I have created it jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/chandelyt/k2otzw4L/1/

Answer (score 4):

When we use frozen columns in kendo grid, the grid gets divided in two tables, but the same row in 2 tables has same uid.
While accessing the row with uid, it gives the content of the unlocked portion only, so your unlocked portion css is getting changed.

```
var dataItem = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.get(1); // 1 will give row with model id 1.
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']").
addClass("k-state-selected");
```

For applying the css to locked portion, use this:

```
$(".k-grid-content-locked").find("tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']").
addClass("k-state-selected");
```

where "k-grid-content-locked" is the class of locked portion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this!  I would've been stuck way longer without this tip!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. It works for me!

```
function onDataBound(arg)
    {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var gridData = grid.dataSource.view();
        var currentUid, currenRow;

        for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
            console.log(gridData[i].Status);
            currentUid = gridData[i].uid;
            if (gridData[i].ContactTitle == "Owner") {
                currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                $(currenRow).addClass("ClassDeleted");
                currenRow = grid.lockedTable.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                $(currenRow).addClass("ClassDeleted");
            }
            else if (gridData[i].ContactTitle == "Sales Representative") {
                var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                $(currenRow).addClass("ClassPublished");
                currenRow = grid.lockedTable.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                $(currenRow).addClass("ClassPublished");
            }

            else if (gridData[i].ContactTitle == "Marketing Manager") {
                var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                $(currenRow).addClass("ClassSaved");
            }

            else if (gridData[i].ContactTitle == "Draft") {
                var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                $(currenRow).addClass("ClassSaved");
            }
            else if (gridData[i].ContactTitle == "Accounting Manager") {
                var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                $(currenRow).addClass("ClassCompleted");
            }
        }
    }
```